# Find the minimum and maximum of $f(x) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n (x-a_k)^2$

Tags: calculus

> Let $a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_n$ be a strictly increasing sequence. Find the minimum and maximum of $f(x) = \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^n (x-a_k)^2$.

**Attempt**

We have
$$\begin{aligned}
f(x) &= (x-a_0)^2+(x-a_1)^2+\cdots+(x-a_n)^2 \\
&= (n+1)x^2-2(a_0+\cdots+a_n)x+(a_0^2+\cdots+a_n^2)
\end{aligned}$$
so we take the first derivative and set it equal to $0$ to get $x = \dfrac{a_0+\cdots+a_n}{n+1}$. Is this the minimum?

Comment: How about computing the second derivative?

Comment: By the way, the hypothesis that $a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_n$ is strictly increasing is irrelevant. The result does not depend on this in any way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each term in the sum $(x-a_k)^2$ is a convex function. Since the sum of convex functions is convex, $f$ is a convex.

Thus, the point where $f'(x)=0$ is a global minimum. The function has no global maximum.

Note that minimizing this function attempts to find the $x$ that minimizes the "squared error" or rather, Euclidian distance, to a bunch of data points: $a_k$. The minimizer turns out to be the sample mean $\frac{1}{n}\sum a_k$. More formally:

(**Edit: note that I will start at $k=1$ while you started at $k=0$. This explains the difference between $n+1$ and $n$ in our final answers**)

$$f'(x)=0$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^n2(x-a_k)=0$$
$$2\sum_{k=1}^n(x-a_k)=0$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^n(x-a_k)=0$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^nx=\sum_{k=1}^na_k$$
$$nx=\sum_{k=1}^na_k$$
$$x=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^na_k$$

Comment: I get $x = \dfrac{a_0+\cdots+a_n}{n+1}$.

Comment: I see why. You start at $k=0$ I start at $k=1$.

Comment: How do we find the minimum value of the function from this $x$ or does it not turn out nicely?

Comment: I suspect it won't turn out nicely.